# How to make the below Python code accessible using Public IP address?

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus

I am quite a novice to Python programming. I am actually tryin to learn prometheus and the below code is to allow a programm accessible from under the http://localhost:8000, which btw works fine in the local browser. However, when I try to access the program through port 8000, using the Public IP of the instance, it does not work though(Port 8000 is open in the SG/Firewall).
Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
import http.server
#from prometheus_client import start_http_server

APP_PORT = 8000
#METRICS_PORT = 8001

class HandleRequests(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>First Application</title></head><body style='color: #333; margin-top: 30px;'><center><h2>Welcome to our first Prometheus-Python application.</center></h2></body></html>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #start_http_server(METRICS_PORT)
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', APP_PORT), HandleRequests)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: To @nick-odell comment, `localhost` is a special loopback|local-only address. Using `localhost` network traffic doesn't leave the local machine (and often doesn't even hit the network card). If a server is bound to localhost, only other servers on the same machine are able to interact with it. `0.0.0.0` corresponds to all network adapters. It may be too broad but it's a common convention to use this address (particularly when running servers in containers) to bind the server's port(s) such that they can be accessed remotely. See [What is localhost?](https://whatismyipaddress.com/localhost)

Comment: I have tried replacing the localhost with 0.0.0.0.  On the Terminal, I got the below messages: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2023 01:09:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33184)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address). Pub IP just fails.